# Label above bar not showing for horizontal bars ios-charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am implementing ios-charts in my project for a horizontal bar chart. I need the values of the individual bars to appear above the bars (since the chart is horizontal, the label should appear on the right of the bar). However, I am unable to make it work. The code is as follows:

```
func setupHorizontalChartView() {

        self.chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
        chartView.dragEnabled = false
        chartView.setScaleEnabled(true)
        chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false

        let chartXAxis = chartView.xAxis
        chartXAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

        let chartLeftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
        chartLeftAxis.labelFont = NSUIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)!
        chartLeftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.darkGray

        chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

        chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true

        let formatter = BarChartFormatter()
        formatter.setValues(values: self.months)

        chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = formatter
        chartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(self.months.count - 1, force: false)

        chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

        chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        chartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false

        chartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    }

    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")

        chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
        chartData.setDrawValues(true)

        chartView.data = chartData
    }
```

`drawValueAboveBarEnabled` has been set to true for the chartView. When I use the same code for BarChartView instead of HorizontalBarChartView, the values of the bars get shown above the bars. However, it doesn't work for horizontal bar chart view.

Answer (score 7):

Setting
`chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0`
helped me.
I've open a discussion for it here [GitHub](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2063)